# getting javax.servlet.ServletException:when running on Tomcat

Tags: java, ssh, servletexception

Thanks all,I'm getting

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be       cast to java.util.List
```

when running my web application on tomcat a day later.if i click any action will have chance getting this exception.but not every time.
anyone can help me?
below is the exception description

```
    description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.util.List
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:515)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:422)
    OnLineExam.Util.CkFilter.doFilter(CkFilter.java:31)
root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.util.List
    OnLineExam.Operation.Library.GetLibraryTree.GetListByHql(GetLibraryTree.java:50)
    OnLineExam.Controller.LibraryController.getLibraryByParentIdAsc(LibraryController.java:53)
    OnLineExam.Controller.LibraryController.Manager(LibraryController.java:61)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor540.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:404)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:229)
    OnLineExam.Util.AuthorizationInterceptor.intercept(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:25)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:184)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:121)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:224)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:223)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:221)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:504)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:422)
    OnLineExam.Util.CkFilter.doFilter(CkFilter.java:31)
```

> GetLibraryTree.java line 50 code below

```
List<Tblibrarytree> resultList=(List<Tblibrarytree>) helper.getMySqlList(hqlStr, null);
```

getMySqlList:

```
 public Object getMySqlList(String HqlCmdStr,List<ParamsModel> ParamsList)
{
    Object  Result=new Object();
    try
    {    
        beginSessionAndTransaction();
        org.hibernate.Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        Query q=session.createQuery(HqlCmdStr);
        //为参数化查询提供参数
        if(ParamsList!=null)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<ParamsList.size();i++)
            {
                q.setString(ParamsList.get(i).getParamsName(), ParamsList.get(i).getParamsValues());
            }
        } 
        Result=q.list(); 
        tx.commit();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        //session.close();
    }
    return Result;
}
```

now,> getMySqlList() change to below

```
public List<T> getMySqlList(String HqlCmdStr,List<ParamsModel> ParamsList)
    {
        List<T> Result=null;
        try
        {    
            beginSessionAndTransaction();
            org.hibernate.Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
            Query q=session.createQuery(HqlCmdStr);
            //为参数化查询提供参数
            if(ParamsList!=null)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<ParamsList.size();i++)
                {
                    q.setString(ParamsList.get(i).getParamsName(), ParamsList.get(i).getParamsValues());
                }
            } 
            Result=q.list(); 
            tx.commit();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            //session.close();
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

Any Suggestions about these codes?

Comment: Please post some code from `GetLibraryTree.java` around line 50.

Comment: @Santosh OK,post success.Any Suggestions about these codes?

Comment: Are getting the same exception after the code changes you shown above?

Comment: @Santosh not getting again after changes until now,thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the exception it looks like you are trying to cast a single object to list of objects. Please check the hql executed in this scenario and run the query manually on the database to check what is actually retrieved.

Comment: thanks you,but why the exception getting in a day later,not beginning?